# AJAX ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net

Добрый вечер!

Программированием занимаюсь совсем недавно, не могу разобраться в одном вопросе.

На странице есть некоторые контейнеры для изображений, сформированных на основе универсального частичного представления:

```
                    <!--конвертер 2-->
                    <div class="w100h31">
                        <div class="w30h100 center">
                            @{Html.RenderAction("ImageControl", "Image", new { imageref = "/Content/Images/69.png", name = "Конвертер 2", i = 0.5 });}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--конвертер 3-->
                    <div class="w100h31">
                        <div class="w30h100 center">
                            @{Html.RenderAction("ImageControl", "Image", new { imageref = "/Content/Images/69.png", name = "Конвертер 3", i = 0 });}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Необходимо чтобы дочерние действия (RenderAction) обновлялись с определенной периодичностью. Ну и соответственно без перезагрузки всей страницы.

Например, раз в десять секунд происходит обновления действия и соответственно если в контроллере, формирующем частичное представление есть изменения зависимых данных, он формировал новое частичное представление.

Answer (score 1):

Привет!

Здесь важно понимать, что в MVC, в отличии от WebForms, нет каких-то волшебных элементов, которые позволят тебе управлять клиентской частью страницы.

Поэтому вопрос с обновлением каких-то конкретных элементов без перезагрузки страницы можно решить только через js.

1) Добавим класс и id контейнера к твоему View, чтобы их различать

```
            <!--конвертер 2-->
            <div class="w100h31">
                <div class="w30h100 center container" containerid="2">
                    @{Html.RenderAction("ImageControl", "Image", new { imageref = "/Content/Images/69.png", name = "Конвертер 2", i = 0.5 });}
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--конвертер 3-->
            <div class="w100h31">
                <div class="w30h100 center container" containerid="3">
                    @{Html.RenderAction("ImageControl", "Image", new { imageref = "/Content/Images/69.png", name = "Конвертер 3", i = 0 });}
                </div>
            </div>
```

2) На наш Ajax-запрос необходимо высылать новый контейнер. Для его формирования создадим View с именем Ajax:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@{Html.RenderAction("ImageControl", "Image", new { imageref = ViewBag.imageHref, name = ViewBag.imageName, i = ViewBag.i });}
```

3) Теперь в контроллере, который генерит твою страницу добавим метод:

```
public ActionResult Ajax(int id) //id будет содержать id контейнера
{         
   //здесь ты пишешь код, который как-то изменяет твой контейнер. Результаты записываешь в переменные ниже
   @ViewBag.imageHref=""; 
   @ViewBag.imageName="";
   @ViewBag.i=1;
   return View("Ajax");
}
```

4) Теперь добавим на страницу с контейнерами скрипт, который будет их обновлять

```
<script>
var timerId = setInterval(function () {
            replaceContainers();
        }, 1000); //выполнять функцию раз в 1 секунду
function replaceContainers(){
    var $c = $(".container").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("containerid"); //получаем id
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/Ajax/" + id, //Home-замени на имя твоего контроллера. 
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,         
            success: function (result) {
                $(this).html(result); //обновляем div
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, p3) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, как только протестирую напишу о результатах. А если этих элементов подразумевается множество( собственно для этого и реализован некоторый ImageControl), возможно скрипт запускать для элементов класса container без привязки к id?

Comment: Скрипт и сейчас запускается для всех элементов класса container. Идентификатор служит только для того, чтобы их различать. Если необходимости в этом нет, то в скрипте необходимо убрать строку `var id = $(this).attr("containerid");`, а урл будет `url: "/Home/Ajax/",`. Из элементов можно убрать параметр `containerid` и в контроллере тоже можно убрать параметр, т.е. получится `public ActionResult Ajax()`

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно отпишусь о результатах